# Near realtime updating of Solr/Sunspot index issue on Websolr/Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, sunspot, websolr

I have a callback on a Model in my rails app as follows

```
after_save :sunspot_index

def sunspot_index
  Sunspot.index( self )
  Sunspot.commit  
end
```

This works great on my local machine and as soon as I update an instance of the class, it's index entry is updated and it's searchable with it's new attributes.

However this same code does not work when deployed to Heroku. This upsets me deeply. Is there an environment/solr config difference preventing this from working?

I'm using Sunspot 1.2.x

**UPDATE:** It seems the reindex does take place, but after a minute or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Websolr who provide the Solr instances as an add-on on Heroku also have a 60 sec delay on commits.

Read more here:

http://help.websolr.com/discussions/questions/269-how-do-i-turn-on-real-time-indexing

Comment: That's correct. Websolr will offer official near-real-time commits when Solr 4.0 is released. Until then, if NRT is a crucial feature, we recommend you check out our other hosted search service, [Bonsai ElasticSearch](http://bonsai.io) (in public beta as of this writing).

Comment: Thanks Nick. Been doing some reading and it seems ElasticSearch fits our requirements better an Solr right now. Will check out Bonsai.